# cart page & checkout is not working (500 http error)

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, shopping-cart, http-error-500

I am using magento 1.9.4.My cart & checkout is working fine for guest users & logged out customers but when user is logged in then whenever he view cart or try to checkout , gets an error of Http 500. Any body know how to fix it ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

500 error will be recorded in your server apache or nginx error logs. Once we know the error, it will make it possible to diagnose.